# How to print a list of strings to standard error in Scala?

Tags: scala, io

This line causes a compile error:

```
astgen.typeError.foreach(System.err.println)
```

typeError is a scala.collection.immutable.List of Strings in the object astgen.

The error I'm getting is:

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method println in class PrintStream of type (java.lang.String)Unit
and  method println in class PrintStream of type (Array[Char])Unit
match expected type (Nothing) => Unit
      astgen.typeError.foreach(System.err.println)
```

I'm new to Scala and don't understand the problem. Using  2.7.7final.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem in version 2.9.1. Which version are you using? Are you talking about scala's List or Java's?

Comment: You should consider upgrading, 2.7.7 is pre-historic. This issue has been fixed in a more recent version.

Comment: Ops, I meant I couldn't reproduce the problem in  2.9.1. And indeed @soc is right, 2.7.7 is paleolithic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Even not being able to exactly reproduce the problem, I do know you can solve the ambiguity by specifying the type:

```
scala> List("a","b","c")
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> res0.foreach(System.err.println(_:String))
a
b
c
```

In this example the `_:String` is unnecessary, it maybe necessary in your use case.

Answer (score 16):

According to [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Standard_error#Via_Scala_Console_API), calling the built-in `Console` API is better than calling the Java runtime library with `System.err`:

```
scala> List("aa", "bb", "cc").foreach(Console.err.println(_))
aa
bb
cc
```

Comment: Only `System.err` logs to stderr as Logback target. `Console.err` does not work when specified as target, it then still logs to stdout.